# Javascript: How to add "div" element right after 2nd generic "p" tag (w/o ID nor Class) inside of every post or content section?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, createelement

How do I go about inserting a custom "div" element that appears right after 2nd generic (w/o adding ID or Class) "p" node/tag  in the content section of every pages I want it to be in, by using JavaScript?

For example:

```
<div id="main-content">
  <p>1st paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>2nd paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>3rd paragraph content.....</p>
</div>
```

The output:

```
<div id="main-content">
  <p>1st paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>2nd paragraph content.....</p>
  <div id="custom-div">Content here...</div>
  <p>3rd paragraph content.....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` with `nth-child`, then grab element and `insertBefore` next sibling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your html:

```
<input type='button' onclick='addText();' value='Add To List'/>
<input type='text' id='input'/>
<div id="main-content">
  <p>1st paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>2nd paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>3rd paragraph content.....</p>
</div>
```

And since you didn't mention jQuery I will provide an answer with plain Javascript:

```
var appender=1;
    function addText(){
        var parentDiv = document.getElementById('main-content');
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;    
        var node = document.createElement("DIV");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(input);
        node.appendChild(textnode);     
        node.id = 'custom-div_' + appender;
        var child = parentDiv.children[2];
        parentDiv.insertBefore(node, child);
        appender++;

    }
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/wJCa3/)

Note that there is a global `var` so you can assign different ID's to your dynamically created elements.

Edit

As per user request, the following code will add that content on load :

```
<body onload="addText()">
<div id="main-content">
  <p>1st paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>2nd paragraph content.....</p>
  <p>3rd paragraph content.....</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the updated Javascript:

```
var appender=1;
function addText(){
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('main-content');      
    var node = document.createElement("DIV");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("This was added dinamically");
    node.appendChild(textnode);     
    node.id = 'custom-div_' + appender;
    var child = parentDiv.children[2];
    parentDiv.insertBefore(node, child);
    appender++;

}
```

Here is the new [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/mRNXp/)

Note that the variable appender is not longer needed I'm leaving in case you want  to merge functionality.

Comment: This works great, but what I want is to have the function called automatically once the page loads up. How to tweak the code for that? Thanks!

Comment: no problem :) see the updated code, It will insert the lines on load now, also  if you find this  answer useful, please consider upvoting and accepting so it reamins useful to other users :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot man! Voting it up now. One last question though... With the "textnode" variable can I possibly write html tags inside of it or just plain texts only?

Comment: no problem! I'm glad it was useful!,  on the `createTextNode` method use plain text, if you want to create elements use `createElement` then append the text to the created element, just like we did with that div

Comment: Hmmm... That seems tough to me. I'm not sure if it's the one I need for purpose. What I was trying to accomplish is to insert a div tag with the ability to write html inside of it and it can contain few elements. Here's what I want to have inside the div tag:

    <div>
    <form>
    <input name="name" type="text"/>
    <input name="email" type="email"/>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
    </div>

Can it be done with that?

Comment: Yes it can be done, I created a new fiddle, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/r7xNm/

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is like this,

```
var node = document.createElement("div");
var textnode = document.createTextNode('Content here...');
node.appendChild(textnode);
node.id = 'custom-div';
var referencenode = document.getElementById('main-content').children[1];
referencenode.parentNode.insertBefore(node, referencenode.nextSibling);
```

the code "referencenode.parentNode.insertBefore(node, referencenode.nextSibling);" will insert the node into after your selected element,

here's the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wjd6ysym/)